# Why Am I Getting A Docker Image Tagging Error Response?

Tags: docker

I'm having an issue when trying to tag an image.

When I run `docker images` it returns the images I have loaded.

Here are two for example.

```
REPOSITORY                                            TAG       IMAGE ID       CREATED         SIZE
messaging-saas                                        0bff18e   2fd822e3d4ef   2 weeks ago     358MB
opensearchproject/opensearch                          1.2.4     6842d435e62e   4 weeks ago     827MB
```

When I run the following command to tag the opensearch image;

`docker tag 6842d435e62e 8675309.dkr.ecr.test.amazonaws.com/wickr/opensearch:1.2.4`

It produces the following:

```
REPOSITORY                                            TAG       IMAGE ID       CREATED         SIZE
messaging-saas                                        0bff18e   2fd822e3d4ef   2 weeks ago     358MB
8675309.dkr.ecr.test.amazonaws.com/wickr/opensearch   1.2.4     6842d435e62e   4 weeks ago     827MB
opensearchproject/opensearch                          1.2.4     6842d435e62e   4 weeks ago     827MB
```

When I try to run;

`docker tag 2fb822e3d4ef 8675309.dkr.ecr.test.amazonaws.com/wickr/messaging-saas:0bff18e`

I get this error;

`Error response from daemon: No such image: 2fb822e3d4ef:latest`

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

You get an error because you try to tag `2fb822e3d4ef`, but the image id is `2fd822e3d4ef` (third character is wrong).

Comment: Geez...you're correct...can't believe I missed that